# form_for Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on using basic AJAX to add a record to a list in place, and I'm having issues using form `form_for`.

Here is my code.

```
<%= form_for ([@product, @product.new]) do |p| %>

    <p>
    <%= p.label :product_part %>
    <%= p.text_field :product_part%>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= p.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

The error I am getting is

```
undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
```

I understand why I am getting the error (`@products` hasn't been "initialized") but I have no idea how to fix this issue (I am sure it's simple). I have seen something about putting a resource in the routes file, but I do not know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to make a form for a new product, you should (in your controller) be setting `@product` to an instance of a new `Product`:

```
# app/controllers/products_controller.rb
def new
  @product = Product.new
end
```

In your view, using `[@product, @product.new]` makes no sense. You can't invoke `new` on an *instance* of a product. It's very unclear why you're not simply using the following, which is the correct use of `form_for` with a new instance of an ActiveRecord model:

```
form_for @product do |p|
```

Comment: Well, I am wanting to use ajax to update the page so I will not be getting an object from the controller everytime I want to create a product. @meagar

Comment: if the form is updated through an ajax request, you would have to set `@product` in the update action of the products_controller and then in a products/update.js.erb file redisplay the form with the new `@product` with something like $("#product-form").replaceWith('#{escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form')}');.  so the response redisplays just the form but not the rest of the page

Comment: @CannonMoyer There is no other place to get a model except from a controller. That's how Rails works. You might get a model which is JSON-encoded in response to an AJAX request, but it's still coming from a controller.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter if he wants it to be async or whatever.. Since form_for is a helper method it must be called at the server end through any of the action in the controller.. So there are essentially 2 solutionsboth are pretty much the same .. Either define an instance variable for **Product.new** in controller action and have form_for use that. Or put this code a partial and pass in the product as a locals

Answer (score 0):

I would say In case you need to look the [form_for helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) ; to understand the behavior of the method.

The method `form_for` It accept the argument as `record, options = {}`. The value of record could be a symbol object or a newly object of respective class in your case Person.new. 
Second argument could be 
`:url, :namespace, :method, :authenticity_token, :remote , :enforce_utf8, :html`

Among them **:remote => true** option is used as the *Ajaxify your request*.

form_for is a helper that assists with writing forms. form_for takes a :remote option. It works like this:

```
<%= form_for(@article, remote: true) do |f| %>
  ....
<% end %>
```

This will generate the following HTML:

```
 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/articles" class="new_article" data-remote="true" id="new_article" method="post">
  ...
 </form>
```

Note the `data-remote="true"`. Now, the form will be submitted by Ajax rather than by the browser's normal submit mechanism.

For more info about [Form-For helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for)

Hope this solve your problem!!!.

Comment: @Cannon let us now whether our answer work for you or you not.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @product = Product.new
      render :form
   end

   def edit
      @product = Product.find params[:id]
      render :form
   end
end

#app/views/products/form.html.erb
<%= form_for @product, remote: true do |f| %>
   <%= p.label :product_part %>
   <%= p.text_field :product_part%>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will do everything you need for both the `new` and `edit` methods (which you raised concerns about in your comments with `@meagar`).

This should be corroborated with the following routes (you can [see why here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :products
```